# Why does finite recursive behaviour cause a crash ? (free(): invalid pointer)

Tags: c++, string, recursion, crash, invalid-pointer

Below is my code just a function called kk that will be recursively called for 10 times so impossible to cause stack overflow, but it crashes with

> Error in `./3': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000602100

Who knows the reason??

```
string kk(string &s)
{
    static  int i=0;
    s+="q";
    i++;
    cout<<"i="<<i<<endl;
    if(i>=10) return s;
    kk(s);
}

int main()
{
    string s="wer";

    cout<<"s="<<kk(s)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Your function signature has `string` as return type, but what do you actually return?

Comment: Did you read the duplicate question of your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60473503/c-c-program-crash-when-treat-string-as-parameter-and-return-value-of-my-functi)?

Comment: This line:     if(i>=10) return s; When recursed for 10 times, string s will be returned?Does it cause problems?

Comment: Yes, ignoring return statement will cause undefined behaviour, but my function will return s until recursed for 10 times,you mean it stil

Comment: still belonged to undefined behiviour??

Comment: Your function does not return a value on every execution path. If you want to return the result of the recursive invocation, that's `return kk(s);`

Comment: that return does not cascade through the recursion, though. You need to replace `kk(s);`  with `else return kk(s);` so that it always returns a value.

Comment: Thanks all!! I know every called of recurse function should have a return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you forgot to put the return keyword in the last line. By putting it, the code is working without errors

```
string kk(string &s)
{
static  int i=0;
s+="q";
i++;
cout<<"i="<<i<<endl;
if(i>=10) return s;
return kk(s);
}

int main()
{
string s="wer";

cout<<"s="<<kk(s)<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**C26444 NO_UNNAMED_RAII_OBJECTS** this was causing the problem.
On every return, the temporary object was getting created and deleted.

Modified the code like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

static  int i = 0;

void kk(std::string& s)
{

    s += "q";
    i++;
    std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl;
    if (i >= 10) return ;
    kk(s);
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "wer";
    kk(s);
    std::cout << "s=" << s << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> i=1
>   i=2 
>   i=3
>   i=4 
>   i=5
>   i=6
>   i=7
>   i=8
>   i=9
>   i=10
>   s=werqqqqqqqqqq